# How can I load a xib file in another view?

Tags: iphone, ios, nib

I have 3 xib files, 3 buttons on all of the xib files and I am loading the view dynamically when a button is pressed.

For instance when button 1 is clicked then view 1 appears and similarly for button 2 and button 3. 
Is there any way to preserve these views like I have selected a tablecell and then I navigate to view 2 and then come back to button 1 and tablecell selected?

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the UINAvigtionController and also apply a method on table 
with in DidSelectRowAtIndexPath
{
[myTableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexpath animated:NO scrollPosition:0];
}

it will help you when you come back.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using Storyboard for having more then one View Controller. Then you can use segues to transition between the controllers.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to use UINavigationController to go from view to view. You'll have to read up on how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Within one viewcontroller, use `addSubview:` to add new views, use `bringSubviewToFront:` or `sendSubviewToBack:` to show different views, optionally `removeFromSuperview`. More options are in the UIView Class Reference.